# Gson successfully parses from variable but not from file

Tags: android, json, file, gson

I have a class and am trying to parse JSON string to instantiate that class. Here is the code and json file:

**JSON:**

```
{'walk': ['walk_1','walk_2'], 'jump': ['jump']}
```

**Class:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AnimationSheet {

    public ArrayList<String> walk, jump;

}
```

**Function**:

```
Gson json = new Gson();
sheet = json.fromJson(jsonFile, AnimationSheet.class);
```

But it gives this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
```

But it parses successfully if i parse it from a variable as follows:

```
Gson json = new Gson();
String txt = "{'walk': ['walk_1','walk_2'], 'jump': ['jump']}";
sheet = json.fromJson(txt, AnimationSheet.class);
```

What is the reason behind this? How can i fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: what is the value of `jsonFile`?

Comment: what's the type of `jsonFile`?

Comment: could you log value of jsonFile

Comment: It is String type and its value set from the contents of the file. It seems that there were some characters which didn't show up in editor as @SDJMcHattie mentioned. Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that the file doesn't contain the same as your `txt` String.  Looking at the message, it looks like perhaps the file has a stray String at the beginning instead of an object which is what it was expecting.  The object in your example String is `{` or in other words a hash, map or dictionary.  If you `println` the contents of the file to the command line, I expect it doesn't have the exact same characters in it.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that there were some other characters in the beginning of the file which didn't show up on editor.